# Presto array contains value from another column (Superset SQL Query)

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I need a query (Superset) to check if my array column contains a value from another column (WHERE clause).
I tried `WHERE x CONTAINS y`, `WHERE x IS IN y`, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [contains](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains) function.

```sql
SELECT contains(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM z
WHERE CONTAINS(x, y) = True
```